# how to suppress error coming when importing a file In python

Tags: python, import, stderr, suppress-warnings

I have a program which imports a file X and look something like this..

```
...
...
importing rest of the stuff
...
print "Debug A"
from CA import &
print "Debug A"
...
```

This gives the output of the program as

```
Debug A
2015-02-24 15:40:03.374 Python[1778:108266] PyObjCPointer created: at 0x10e565160 of type @
Debug B
```

I have tried using

```
a) warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
b) 
err(or stdout, tried this too) = sys.stderr
from CA import &
sys.stderr = err
```

But i just am not being able to get rid of this message. Any suggestions please? 
Also when i run this file by  `python abc > somefile`

it still shows up but `python abc 2> somefile`, takes it away, so seems like its an stderr.